# Neteeza sqoop option file - how to handle in code promotion

Tags: hadoop, netezza, sqoop

I am using Hadoop Sqoop to to export data from hadoop to neteeza. And I have create a options file for this.

Option file content is as mentione below

```
-connect
jdbc:netezza://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:5480/
--username
XXXX 
--password
***************
```

Now I am not sure how to use this file in code promotion, is there any way I could write logic in this file to choose parameter based on the Environment I am using.

Currently everytime I have to change the environment I need to change this file, which creates a lots of version of this file and if someone forgets to update it creates a lots of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t really a netezza question as such, I would expect it to be something you would have to solve at the ‘client’ end of things.
At our place we have a set of naming conventions to separate environments (DEV,TEST,PROD) from each other. All system users, configure files (like this) database names and network aliases are build over this keyword.

If you create a configuration file per environment and put the environment name into the file name, you can avoid most problems.

An example:
In environment PROD,

- System user: SQOOP_USER_PROD
- Config file: sqoop_PROD.conf
- Database1: STAGING_PROD
- Database2: WAREHOUSE_PROD
- Network alias: NZPROD.yourdomain.com

Can you follow me?